# Fake urls on local nodejs setup

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node JS server running on my local pc. This pc is not accessible from outside.

What I see is below list of fake urls in the server log.  Where is this URL requests coming from?  What kind of attack is this?

Does my node js packages has a malicious code?

```
GET / 200 453.427 ms - 517
OPTIONS / 200 0.901 ms - 8
PROPFIND / 404 57.119 ms - 1100
OPTIONS * 404 28.097 ms - 1082
GET /Rapid7/JBoss/version-check-UvBo5i.html 404 16.797 ms - 1100
GET /console/login/LoginForm.jsp 404 16.349 ms - 1100
GET /igsponsor 404 13.136 ms - 1100
GET / 200 14.813 ms - 517
GET /spiffymcgee.jsp 404 5.804 ms - 1100
GET / 200 6.166 ms - 517
GET / 200 10.456 ms - 517
GET /jbossws/ 404 9.220 ms - 1100
GET /invoker/ 404 8.065 ms - 1100
GET /jbossmq-httpil/ 404 9.178 ms - 1100
GET /status/ 404 8.007 ms - 1100
GET / 200 13.990 ms - 517
GET /reviews 404 8.054 ms - 1100
GET / 200 8.699 ms - 517
GET /login 404 5.635 ms - 1100
GET / 200 5.436 ms - 517
GET /login 404 6.158 ms - 1100
GET / 200 4.999 ms - 517
GET /login.action 404 4.050 ms - 1100
GET /login 404 4.466 ms - 1100
GET /login 404 6.062 ms - 1100
GET /owa/auth/logon.aspx 404 6.262 ms - 1100
GET /owa/auth/logon.aspx 404 5.838 ms - 1100
GET /owa/auth/logon.aspx 404 4.955 ms - 1100
GET /console/App.html 404 5.447 ms - 1100
GET / 200 6.892 ms - 517
GET /php/login.php 404 4.214 ms - 1100
GET / 200 7.227 ms - 517
GET /CHANGELOG.txt 404 5.242 ms - 1100
GET /wordpress/readme.html 404 4.887 ms - 1100
GET / 200 5.062 ms - 517
GET /wordpress 404 5.213 ms - 1100
GET /wordpress/wp-login.php 404 6.610 ms - 1100
GET /index.php/login 404 4.692 ms - 1100
GET /spiffymcgee.cfm 404 4.504 ms - 1100
GET /servlet/ 404 5.111 ms - 1100
GET / 200 7.511 ms - 517
GET /administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml 404 4.363 ms - 1100
GET /administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.xml 404 4.109 ms - 1100
GET /language/en-GB/en-GB.xml 404 5.029 ms - 1100
GET / 200 6.197 ms - 517
GET /xmldata?item=All 404 4.925 ms - 1100
GET / 200 7.789 ms - 517
GET /spiffymcgee.nsf 404 7.321 ms - 1100
GET /jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa 404 5.877 ms - 1100
GET /secure/Dashboard.jspa 404 4.130 ms - 1100
GET /login.jsp 404 3.840 ms - 1100
GET /console/faces/com_sun_web_ui/jsp/version/version_30.jsp 404 6.408 ms - 1100
GET /console/faces/com_sun_web_ui/jsp/version/version_4.jsp 404 6.395 ms - 1100
GET /phpmyadmin/ 404 5.518 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/htsearch?Exclude=%60/etc/passwd%60 404 5.433 ms - 1100
GET /c99.php 404 6.251 ms - 1100
POST /cgi/login 404 47.299 ms - 1100
POST /data/login 404 53.409 ms - 1100
POST /xmlrpc.php 404 22.703 ms - 1100
POST /serendipity/serendipity_xmlrpc.php 404 10.856 ms - 1100
GET /jkstatus/ 404 14.917 ms - 1100
GET /conf/ssl/apache/integrity.key 404 10.338 ms - 1100
POST /serendipity/xmlrpc.php 404 8.799 ms - 1100
GET /conf/ssl/apache/integrity-smartcenter.key 404 5.615 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/scheduler/ 404 6.504 ms - 1100
POST /drupal/xmlrpc.php 404 5.956 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/servermanager/ 404 13.669 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/componentutils/cfcexplorer.cfc?method=getcfcinhtml&name=CFIDE.componentutils.cfcexplorer&path=../../../license.txt 404 11.957 ms - 1100
POST /bblog/xmlrpc.php 404 5.526 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/componentutils/cfcexplorer.cfc?method=getcfcinhtml&name=CFIDE.componentutils.cfcexplorer&path=../../../../license.html 404 10.053 ms - 1100
POST /CFIDE/adminapi/administrator.cfc? 404 11.261 ms - 1100
POST /blogs/xmlsrv/xmlrpc.php 404 9.342 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminapi/customtags/soft404validationcheck.cfm 404 4.703 ms - 1100
POST /xmlsrv/xmlrpc.php 404 5.444 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/soft404validationcheck.cfm 404 8.133 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminapi/customtags/fusebox.cfm 404 4.375 ms - 1100
POST /xmlrpc/xmlrpc.php 404 5.083 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminapi/customtags/adss.cfm 404 4.595 ms - 1100
POST /script/xmlrpc.php 404 4.009 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/AIR/ 404 5.960 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/h.cfm 404 4.604 ms - 1100
HEAD http://www.google.com:80/ 200 6.972 ms - 517
GET /CFIDE/wizards/common/ 404 4.086 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/administrator/enter.cfm?locale=../../../../../../../lib/password.properties%00en 404 7.514 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/php.ini 404 5.903 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/h9.cfm 404 4.094 ms - 1100
GET /phpmyadmin/ 404 4.024 ms - 1100
POST /cgi-bin/home.tcl 404 5.114 ms - 1100
GET /~bin/true 404 5.430 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/help.cfm 404 5.527 ms - 1100
POST /cgi-bin/test-cgi 404 3.858 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/componentutils/ 404 3.889 ms - 1100
GET /scripts/tools/newdsn.exe?driver=Microsoft%2BAccess%2BDriver%2B%28*.mdb%29&dsn=Web%20SQL&dbq=c:%5Ctemp%5Cxyz.mdb&newdb=CREATE_DB&attr= 404 4.677 ms - 1100
GET /AdvWorks/equipment/catalog_type.asp?ProductType=|shell(%22c:cmd.exe%22)| 404 4.392 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/i.cfm 404 4.823 ms - 1100
GET /ASPSamp/AdvWorks/equipment/catalog_type.asp?ProductType=|shell(%22c:cmd.exe%22)| 404 3.932 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/orm/ 404 4.252 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminapi/base.cfc?wsdl 404 3.957 ms - 1100
POST / 404 5.537 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/r.cfm 404 4.286 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/view-source?../../../../../../../etc/passwd 404 4.063 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/awstats.pl?debug=1 404 7.055 ms - 1100
GET /crossdomain.xml 404 3.970 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/faxsurvey?/bin/cat%20/etc/passwd 404 4.197 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/awstats/awstats.pl?debug=1 404 4.098 ms - 1100
GET /README.txt 404 3.921 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/faxquery?/bin/cat%20/etc/passwd 404 5.752 ms - 1100
GET /_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll 404 11.194 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminapi/customtags/l10n.cfm?attributes.id=test&attributes.file=../../administrator/mail/download.cfm&filename=../../lib/password.properties&attributes.locale=it&attributes.var=it&attributes.jscript=false&attributes.type=text/html&attributes.charset=UTF-8&thisTag.executionmode=end&thisTag.generatedContent=test 404 6.015 ms - 1100
POST /index.htm 404 4.393 ms - 1100
TRACE / 404 4.289 ms - 1100
GET /bb/ 404 6.852 ms - 1100
GET /?Class.classLoader.resources.cacheObjectMaxSize=foo 200 6.563 ms - 517
GET /CFIDE/appdeployment/ 404 8.525 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/htgrep/file=index.html&hdr=/etc/passwd 404 4.959 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/websocket/ 404 6.200 ms - 1100
GET /struts2-showcase/employee/save.action 404 4.984 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/portlets/ 404 6.358 ms - 1100
GET /common/index.jsf 404 4.763 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminapi/customtags/l10n.cfm?attributes.id=test&attributes.file=../../administrator/mail/download.cfm&filename=../lib/password.properties&attributes.locale=it&attributes.var=it&attributes.jscript=false&attributes.type=text/html&attributes.charset=UTF-8&thisTag.executionmode=end&thisTag.generatedContent=test 404 4.718 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/wizards/common/utils.cfc?method=verifyldapserver&vserver=localhost&vport=22&vstart=&vusername=&vpassword=&returnformat=json 404 4.245 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/adminiapi/ 404 6.210 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/services/ 404 5.988 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/administrator/ 404 4.210 ms - 1100
GET /CFIDE/administrator/enter.cfm 404 4.537 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/awstats.pl?PluginMode=:print+%22x%22%2e(1042+%2b+1099)%2e%22x%22; 404 3.929 ms - 1100
GET /struts2-blank/example/HelloWorld.action 404 3.957 ms - 1100
GET /?class.classLoader.resources.cacheObjectMaxSize=foo 200 6.800 ms - 517
GET /cgi-bin/htmlscript?../../../../../../../etc/passwd 404 4.158 ms - 1100
GET /cgi-bin/awstats/awstats.pl?PluginMode=:print+%22x%22%2e(1042+%2b+1099)%2e%22x%22; 404 4.301 ms - 1100
POST /flex2gateway/http 404 5.857 ms - 1100
GET / 200 15.168 ms - 517
POST /flex2gateway/httpsecure 404 15.935 ms - 1100
POST /messagebroker/http 404 7.137 ms - 1100
POST /messagebroker/httpsecure 404 3.736 ms - 1100
POST /blazeds/messagebroker/http 404 3.765 ms - 1100
POST /blazeds/messagebroker/httpsecure 404 3.731 ms - 1100
POST /samples/messagebroker/http 404 3.869 ms - 1100
GET /r7.txt 404 4.059 ms - 1100
POST /samples/messagebroker/httpsecure 404 5.445 ms - 1100
POST /lcds/messagebroker/http 404 3.682 ms - 1100
POST /lcds/messagebroker/httpsecure 404 3.802 ms - 1100
POST /lcds-samples/messagebroker/http 404 3.731 ms - 1100
POST /lcds-samples/messagebroker/httpsecure 404 3.730 ms - 1100
PUT /r7.txt 404 3.707 ms - 1100
GET /r7.txt 404 3.786 ms - 1100
HEAD /index.php 404 6.588 ms - 1100
POST /cgi-bin/webcgi/login 404 4.221 ms - 1100
GET / 200 5.813 ms - 517
GET /portal/diag/index.jsp 404 3.786 ms - 1100
GET /miners 304 57.834 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 15.845 ms - -
GET /xmldata?item=All 404 85.536 ms - 1100
```

Is there any possibility to increase the `npm start` debug level?  I would like to see the source IP where the GET requests are coming from as well as the timestamp.

Comment: Increased the npm log level using the command 'npm config set loglevel debug'.  Hope I will get more info regarding the question.

Comment: Look in your package.json, under the scripts section. What is in your "start" script? Some apps use the debug library which you can enable like so: `DEBUG=* npm start`

Comment: Why do you say that the PC is not accessible from the outside? Out side of itself or outside of your network?

Comment: @justin.m.chase its in LAN network and the port 80 in which npm is running at is not opened or forwarded to the pc.

Comment: @justin.m.chase the "start" contains below line "start": "node ./bin/www".  the www is a shell script which creates an 'http' object using 'http' package and calls 'server = http.createServer(app);'.

Comment: @justin.m.chase ´DEBUG=* npm start´ did give me some more output but not the request originator IP.  Is there a flag to also see that?

Comment: It depends on the app. You'd have to look in the code it probably isn't logging it if you don't see it. You can just dig around and modify it.

Comment: It looks like there is someone scanning your server for exploits. See https://github.com/carnal0wnage/Metasploit-Code/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/scanner/coldfusion_scanner.rb

Answer (score -1):

Implement CORS in your application, then all the request will pass thru it and you can restrict request which is coming from the different domain. 
If you are using expressJS then you can do it in the following manner.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // here you can restrict Origin
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but my question is why I have such wired requirests and who is generating them?  Where the requests are coming from?.  As the PC is not accessible outside LAN, is it that the packages installed vis npm has some malicious code?